# Why does .clearfix class not work on floating element?

Tags: html, css, floating, clearfix

In this thread: [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

I saw the best answer says the ***clearfix can be added directly to the last floating element***:

> With clearfix, you only need to

write HTML code:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div style="float: left;" class="clearfix">Sidebar</div>
</div>
```

and CSS code:

```
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

**However**, when I tried to add `clearfix` to the floating element, it doesn't work at all (as can be seen in the snippet below) :

```css
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}

div#container {
    background-color: green;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
.floating {
    float: left;
    margin: 1px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class='floating'>1</div>
    <div class='floating clearfix'>2</div>

</div>
```

As can be found in the result, the `#container`'s height is still `0`. It seems that the clearfix doesn't work and cannot be added to the last floating element directly. Is it true? Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: Where did you see "clearfix can be added directly to the last floating element"?

Comment: @Pangloss In the code he pasted: `<div style="float: left;" class="clearfix">Sidebar</div>`  , which I couldn't fully understand. I think Sidebar should be a floating element as well as a container of floating elements..

Comment: It has clearfix class sets on both the container and the floating element, I believe the 2nd one doesn't do anything. `:after` inserts a pseudo element at the end of the element, but it is still **inside** the element itself.

Comment: @hanfeisun I think the poster applied the `.clearfix` class by accident to the wrong element. They did apply it to the parent DIV of the sidebar DIV which would be correct and be in-line with some of the answers posted to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've to use the `clearfix` on the `container`.

```css
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}

div#container {
    background-color: green;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
.floating {
    float: left;
    margin: 1px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
    <div class='floating'>1</div>
    <div class='floating'>2</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `:after` element that should clear the children at the end of the container, not inside the floating element itself. All you have to do is give the container the class `clearfix`, like this:

```
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
    <div class="floating">1</div>
    <div class="floating">2</div>
</div>
```